# How to create line breaks between extended attributes OSX xattr (jwodder)

Tags: macos, attributes

When using xattr at the command line, is it possible to enter a line break at the end of the name:value pair somehow ?

I noticed that when listing the extended attributes of a file:

xattr -l file

The attributes are listed with a line break between each one, making it a lot easier to read them.

However when **I** write extended attributes to a file and then list them, they are bunched one line after the next.

Comment: What do you mean by "write extended attributes to a file"? What is "jwodder"?

Comment: @Daniel Beck, Extended File Attributes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes Xattr is the name of several applications that do similar but different tasks so it can be rather confusing to differentiate. I put the name (jwodder) there because that is one developer responsible for one of the xattr applications, Bob Ippolito http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xattr is another, then there is Matt Lye http://sourceforge.net/projects/xattr, and there are probably more. I don't know who is responsible for the version that comes installed with OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "a line break [between each one]" you mean "a blank line," that blank line is only inserted between different files' attribute listings; a list of attributes for a single file does not separate them with blanks.  If you want a blank line after every attribute, the only way to do this would be to [patch xattr](http://gist.github.com/961599) and recompile.

Comment: I wasn't expecting to receive an answer from the coder, but thank you very much for your application and the patched version. I will certainly follow that link.